# converting a float string to a float

Tags: c++

say I have a string as such (I am actually getting this value from somewhere else)

```
std::string val = "2.31";
```

Now I am doing something like this

```
float f = atof(val);
```

Now f has something like 2.31xxxxxxxxxxx

any suggestion on how I could just get two places after the decimal point ? such that f looks like 2.3100000...

Comment: `f` is definitely not "something like 2.3131333e-xx".

Comment: What compile are you using? `atof` takes a `const char*`.

Comment: You are right it is a pretty large digit no

Comment: It is not possible to set a `float` object to exactly 2.31 in an implementation that uses IEEE-754 32-bit binary floating-point because 2.31 is not representable in IEEE-754 32-bit binary format. The closest representable value is 2.309999942779541015625.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can never get exact value for every input in float. Thats due to representation of floating point in computer. And thats also why you cant do `==` on floats. If you want precision, you will have to use other formats (BCD ?)

Comment: `1.0==1.0` is just fine.

Comment: @BenjaminBannier: “1.0” is an input, not every input.

Comment: @BenjaminBannier Let's agree that it appeared to be working so far, according to your experience.

Comment: @BenjaminBannier thats because its hard coded in code and not from variable. If you do this, compiler do some optimalization and place both numbers as same in memory

Comment: @MartinPerry No, not quite.

Comment: @MartinPerry: `1.0 == 1.0` is true because `1.0` is exactly representable and every C++ implementation of even the slightest quality converts an input string of “1.0” to exactly 1. Floating-point does not introduce random changes to numbers, and they do not fluctuate spontaneously.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I have also seen 1.0 from string represented as 1.000000000001 (or some junk at the end). Hovever, 1.0 is just one float from all possible values, so its not quite good to argument with that.

Comment: @MartinPerry: Show a self-contained compilable example.

Comment: @MartinPerry: My snarky comment was not a general, always true statement, but just geared towards the black magic your answer implied.

Comment: @MartinPerry: It's nothing to do with variables - even `double third() { return 1.0 / 3.0; } int main() { double a = 1.0 / 3.0; if ( a == third() ) { ...` ought to evaluate to `true`. What is true is that you often can't count on two different routes getting you to what seems like it ought to be the same number, e.g. `if ( 0.1 * 3 == 0.3 )` will generally not evaluate to `true`.

Answer (score 1):

Binary floating points cannot represent fractional, decimal values exactly. The value stored in a `float` will be an approximation in most cases. However, using the right algorithm for printing will restore the original digits if there are no more than `std::numeric_limits<float>::digits10` digits used.

Answer (score 0):

```
template <typename T>
T val(const std::string& s)
{
    T x;   
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss  << s;
    ss >> x;
   return x;
}

int main() {
float f =val<float>("2.31");
std::cout<<f; 
 }
```

Comment: This does not set a `float` to 2.31 as the question requests.

Comment: @EricPostpischil 2.31 is [shown](http://ideone.com/XBdQ21) two decimal places

Comment: The question title indicates conversion to `float` is desired. Sending a numeral with two decimal places to output is not converting to `float`. The actual `float` object in the code you linked to does not have the exact value 2.31.